# Rename CSS classes in Luma theme for Magento2

Tags: magento2, css, luma-theme

I am customizing the Luma theme for a project and notice that the homepage blocks of Luma have very particular names for their CSS classes, for example home-erin, home-t-shirts etc.

I would like to rename the classes but always seem to miss some classes, which causes the frontpage images/blocks to break. So, all this manual labor to update classnames like home-pants to home-mid, home-eco to home-sale so our client knows what is what seems to be a hell of a job.

My actual questions:
1. Does anybody every tried the same thing as I do right now? If so, how?
2. Is there anybody who can think of a way of doing this quick, easy and with the best change of renaming all of the classes (so you don't forget anything)
3. Should I stop trying and just rewrite the whole thing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for option 4: Don't change the provided templates by changing classes.

I know: Magentos' class names are not the most modern or logical one, they don't strictly follow any semantic approach (like BEM for example). But I've been working for quite a while now with Magento (since 1.6) and if there is one thing I can tell you is: "Do it 'The Magento Way'(tm)".

Don't try to swim upstream; I've made this mistake far too often myself. It's a hell of a job and as soon as the first patch or update comes out you have to do a lot of additional work. Also take into account that if you are going to use extensions you most likely have to re-template those as well, because they are most likely to follow the Magento conventions.

When it comes to templating / styling, add your own classes, re-use Magento styling, and try to do as much as possible by tweaking variables (you'd be surprised how much is possible with just that). Or you could always go headless ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's good to see a reply from you, because I know that will result in an answer I can actually go with.

Your answer is exactly what I was affraid of what would happen and but i had to ask, as the Dutch saying goes, while knowing better. I also forgot to mention those classnames are results from sample data, which makes it even harder to solve this in a solid way, after removing Sample data. 

Thank you for your fast response. Have a nice day!